# How do I check what URL an image has been set with?

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, uiimage

I set an `image` using an `url` like this:

```
[self.imageView setMyImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[trip.destination getHeaderImageUrl] ]];
```

```
- (void)setMYImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url {
    [self setBackground];

    if(url.absoluteString.length >0){
        __block UIImageView *safeSelf = self;
        UIImage *placeholderImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"placeholderpic_%@.png", NSLocalizedString(@"LanguageCode" , @"")]];
        [self setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]
                    placeholderImage:placeholderImage
                             success:nil
                             failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
                                 safeSelf.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"placeholderpic_%@_missing.png", NSLocalizedString(@"LanguageCode" , @"")]];
                             }
         ];
    }else{
        self.image = [self missingImage];
    }
}
```

Now, is there a way to check the `imageView` `url` after it has been set. Like, `NSLog(@"%@", self.imageView.usingURL)`. I would like to check if it's the same as another `url` using a conditional. Something like this:

```
if(self.imageView.usingURL == [NSURL URLWithString:[trip.destination getHeaderImageUrl]])
```

Comment: It's not possible to get the URL info from UIImage. But this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18134602/3050006) could be a solution for your problem as well. You can send an identifier or use the URL's `absoluteString` value as an identifier in UIImage which would enable you to identify your loaded images' urls.

Comment: `setImageWithURLRequest:placeholderImage:success:failure:`: What is that lib you are using? There might be a value set there on the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this category to add property in UIImageView

```
@interface UIImageView (URLImageView)
    @property NSURL* usingURL;
@end

@implementation UIImageView (URLImageView)]
@end
```

Now when image downloading and set to image view assign url to image view like

```
self.imageView.usingURL = yourURL
```

Now you can access this url to compare.